# What to do with the configuration test cell after configuring the MinION with it?

Tags: nanopore, ngs, long-reads, minion

What to do with the configuration test cell after configuring the MinION with it?

I received a MinION with a configuration test cell in it. After running a configuration in the MinKNOW software while the CTC was in the MinION, I wonder what to do with the CTC? Am I going to need it later or can I throw it away? If I should keep it, in what conditions should I keep it (temperature, light, etc.)?

Also, do you know why we need to do a configuration of the MinION the first time?

I posted this question on [Biology Stackexchange](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/70319/what-to-do-with-the-configuration-test-cell-after-configuring-the-minion-with-it) as well but maybe the community here will be more receptive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep it, in case you need to do another configuration later on. I have used mine for that purpose.

I think storage doesn't really matter, I just put it in a drawer somewhere. Keep it away from liquids and extreme temperatures :)